# Having trouble simplifying $\frac{5}{3}\ln12 - \frac{2}{3}\ln6 - \frac{5}{3}\ln7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I did a definite integral and I was wondering if I could simplify that any further and if so, how? Not really an expert on the identities of the natural logarithm.

Comment: $\ln 12=\ln (2\cdot 6)=\ln 2+\ln 6$. Don't see any further possibilities to simplify.

Answer (score 5):

You can take it as $$\frac 13\left(5\ln 12 - 2\ln 6-5\ln 7\right)=\frac 13\ln \left(\frac {12^5}{6^27^5}\right)$$ and you can cancel some factors inside the logarithm if you want

Answer (score 1):

All we can do is:
$$
\frac{5}{3}\ln12 - \frac{2}{3}\ln6 - \frac{5}{3}\ln7=\frac{1}{3}\left(5\ln 2 +5 \ln 6 -2 \ln 6 -5 \ln 7 \right)=
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{3}\left(5\ln 2 +3 \ln 6 -5 \ln 7 \right)=
\frac{5}{3}\left(\ln 2 -\ln 7 \right)+\ln 6
$$